# Check if function is user defined in LLVM-IR or not

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I am writing a `LLVM` pass which prints function name only if it is user-defined (which are defined by the user in the source file).

I cannot find any way to distinguish the user-defined function from the initialization function (or static constructors). I tried checking if the function is just declared or defined, but it does not work as there some init functions are defined (like `__cxx_global_var_init`).

Answer (score 1):

At pass-time, I know of no way to accomplish what you're trying to do.

That said, Clang provides a way to determine this during initial compilation. See: [clang::SourceManager::isInSystemHeader()](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1SourceManager.html#aa728bad682c5216d9efa45c03404447a). You would have to write a Clang plugin or a libTooling-based program to take advantage of this as the information is gone once opt is executed. Here is a contrived example of how to do so using an AST visitor:

```
bool VisitFunctionDecl(clang::FunctionDecl* funcDecl)
{
  if (sourceManager.isInSystemHeader(funcDecl->getLocStart()))
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```